# Select IDs that do not exist in a table from a given set in where clause

Tags: mysql

I have a set of userID's:
`(512,5,13,14,67)`
 and a table containing the following:

```
+----+--------+
| Id | userID |
+----+--------+
|  1 |    512 |
|  2 |     13 |
|  3 |     14 |
|  4 |     51 |
|  5 |      6 |
+----+--------+
```

Some of those userID's in the set do not exist in a table. E.g. userID `5` and userID `64` do not exist.

When I execute `Select * from mytable where userID NOT IN (512,5,13,14,67)` it will display the rows with userIDs `6` and `51`

```
+----+--------+
| Id | userID |
+----+--------+
|  4 |     51 |
|  5 |      6 |
+----+--------+
```

I would like to do something like:
`SELECT userID FROM my TABLE WHERE NOT EXISTS IN (1,5,10,15)`

and get as a result:

```
+-------+--------+
|  Id   | userID |
+-------+--------+
| NULL  |      5 |
| NULL  |     64 |
+-------+--------+
```

My table contain million rows and the search set may contain 1000 ids to search for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand your problem correctly you are looking for.

```
SELECT 
   NULL AS id 
 , search_filter.userID
FROM (
  SELECT 
   5 AS userID
  UNION
  SELECT
    64 AS userID
  # [...]
) AS search_filter
LEFT JOIN
 your_table
ON
 search_filter.userID = your_table.userID
WHERE 
 your_table.userID IS NULL
```

> The search set could be 1000 ids so I cannot execute the query like
>   that.

Then using a CSV search list which will be parsed by nested `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` functions in combination with a SQL number generator is your only and best option.

```
SELECT 
   NULL AS id 
 , search_filter.userID
FROM (
  SELECT 
   DISTINCT 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(init_search.search_list, ',', sql_number_generator.number), ',', -1
    ) AS userID
FROM (

SELECT
  @number := @number + 1 AS number
FROM (
  (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) row1
  CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) row2
  CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) row3 
  CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) row4    
  CROSS JOIN 
  (SELECT @number:=0) AS init_user_params
)  
) AS sql_number_generator
CROSS JOIN (
 SElECT '512,5,13,14,67' AS search_list 
) AS init_search
) AS search_filter
LEFT JOIN
 your_table
ON
 search_filter.userID = your_table.userID
WHERE 
 your_table.userID IS NULL
```

**Results**

```
| id  | userID |
| --- | ------ |
|     | 5      |
|     | 67     |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/shPBWF5qnoFHmt49F8WjSp/2)

Comment: Thanks Raymond, no this is not what I am after. The search set could be 1000 ids so I cannot execute the query like that.

Comment: *"no this is not what I am after. The search set could be 1000 ids so I cannot execute the query like that"* @PanosKal. only way possible.. well i know a other trick which involves very tricky SQL..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have thought of the same solution as you. but you mentioned another method for a scenario like this? I am a big fan of SQL tricks. I look forward to learning from you and this trick of yours :D

Comment: I think I tried almost every trick available but I also think that this is impossible. The complexity of this search I think that will require great computational effort. I was wondering if there is a trick available and I was also wondering how heavy this query will be.

Comment: *"I think I tried almost every trick available but I also think that this is impossible."* Well @PanosKal. using a SQL number generator is the best and only possible solution.. Keep in mind that this SQL number generator generates 10000 numbers https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/shPBWF5qnoFHmt49F8WjSp/2 so removing or adding CROSS JOIN's on the fly when needed will "optimize" it.

Comment: What a monster query XD, love it when people come up with things like this. but imho, not really sure if it is a good idea to do this in practice. nevertheless, well done Raymond!

Comment: *"What a monster query XD, love it when people come up with things like this. but imho, not really sure if it is a good idea to do this in practice. nevertheless"* Well @RyanTan i've sinned before using this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2548147+sql+number+generator) as it can be very usefull in some situations from dynamic SQL generation to HTML parsing or replacing MySQL 8 JSON_TABLE ..