# How to check for each rows if it exists in a Mysql table using a single query?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have an array that holds a list of ids and i need to check foreach of the ids if it exists in the mysql table or not.

Checking for one of them will be easy with:

```sql
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM fooTable WHERE id = 1)
```

assuming the id to check was `1`.

The problem could be solved by using a loop in a programming language but what if the array's size is about 10000? that means executing the query 10000 times right?

What i want to know is if there is a way to write a statement that will return a result set that will contains the result of all the test like this

```
ID      Found
1       true  (Exists in the table)
2       false (Does'nt exist in the table)
...     ...
```

This could get all the rows that exists

```sql
SELECT id, true as "Found" FROM fooTable WHERE id in(1,2,3,4,5...)
```

but i need to also get the rows of the id's that doesn't exists.

Comment: Use [`IN()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in)

Comment: What are you going to do with it after checking? If you thinking to insert/update it might cause race condition(s)..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select IDs that do not exist in a table from a given set in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56804146/select-ids-that-do-not-exist-in-a-table-from-a-given-set-in-where-clause)

Comment: *"but i need to also get the rows of the id's that doesn't exists."* Check mine duplication link and mine answer there it matches your user case..

Comment: Oh thanks, it is exactly the approach i was thinking about but i couldn't find out how to use the FORM clause without using an actual table.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `IN` or `NOT IN`
To get a list of rows of all Ids that exist in table you can use `SELECT ID FROM FOOTABLE WHERE ID [NOT] IN (SELECT ID FROM BARTABLE)` 
If you want to get the IDs that exists use `IN` and if you want to get IDs that doesn't exist simply use `NOT IN`
These queries returns all the rows that do or doesn't match with your ID
If you want just a boolean answer you can simply compare the `COUNT()` of your tables

Comment: This will result in listing either all id's of footable that are found in bartable or all id's in footable that doesn't exist in bartable... the problem is your answer is using two table but i only used one table with bartable as an array from a programming language...

Comment: But check the duplication link if you are curious of what i wanted to achieve.