# If value doesn't exist in column set to 0

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the number of players per race and if there's a race with no players then set it to 0.

The table is populated from C++, so the job player needs to be displayed in the same order as the C++ enum.

The player table stores all the data from players, and the job column is NOT NULL, since to create a player it's obligatory to select the job. I want to display race count as 0 if there's no player with that race.

I already tried with COALESCE but no luck.

Also saw other topics about using JOIN but doesn't apply here. I only have one table to work this.

My current query:

```sql
SELECT
player.job AS race,
Count(player.job) AS count_races
FROM
player
GROUP BY
race
ORDER BY
FIELD(race, 0, 4, 5, 1, 2, 6, 7, 3, 8, 9) ASC;
```

What I getting:

```
race    count_races
0       5
5       3
1       2
2       6
6       2
3       4
```

What I was expecting to get:

```
race    count_races
0       5
4       0
5       3
1       2
2       6
6       2
7       0
3       4
8       0
9       0
```

My table structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `player`  (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `name` varchar(24) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NONAME',
  `job` tinyint(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `dir` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `x` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `y` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `z` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `map_index` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `exit_x` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `exit_y` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `exit_map_index` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `hp` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `playtime` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `level` tinyint(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `last_play`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `name_idx`(`name`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `account_id_idx`(`account_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT = 1114 CHARACTER SET = latin1 COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;
```

Comment: So you want missing rows to be synthesised with some default value? Not sure why `JOIN` "doesn't apply" here, or why you can't do this at your application layer?

Comment: Can I use JOIN without using a different table? I'm doing this in the query because would be easier to then show the graphic on the website (AJAX)

Comment: a race without players means that `job` column has `NULL` value ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select IDs that do not exist in a table from a given set in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56804146/select-ids-that-do-not-exist-in-a-table-from-a-given-set-in-where-clause)

Comment: i added a duplicate but consider display data "issues"  like missing values to be handled by the application instead

Comment: Yes, self-joins are a thing

Comment: @ths the player table stores all the data from players, and the job column is NOT NULL, since to create a player it's obligatory to select the job. I want to display race count as 0 if no players selected that race.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I edited my question, I don't believe the other question can answer mine. Also added my player table structure and explained a little better.

Comment: You manually change the create table statement.. `PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `last_play`) USING BTREE,`  there is not a column `last_play`..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I didn't post the entire table, it's huge and the other fields aren't really important for this problem.

Comment: fair enough, i posted a answer by the way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Quote (comment) from Karbust:**
>   I edited my question, I don't believe the other question can answer mine. Also added my player table structure and explained a little better.

Yes it can but the trick is adding a co-related subquery to `COUNT(*)`.

```
SELECT 
    search_filter.job
  , (SELECT
       COUNT(*)
     FROM player player_inner
     WHERE player_inner.job = player_outer.job
    ) AS count_races
FROM (
  SELECT 
   0 AS job
  UNION
  SELECT
    4 AS job
  UNION
  SELECT
    5 AS job  
  UNION
  SELECT
    1 AS job
  UNION
  SELECT
    2 AS job   
  UNION
  SELECT
    6 AS job   
  UNION
  SELECT
    7 AS job  
  UNION
  SELECT
    3 AS job   
  UNION
  SELECT
    8 AS job  
  UNION
  SELECT
    9 AS job    
  # [...]
) AS search_filter
LEFT JOIN
 player player_outer
ON
 search_filter.job = player_outer.job
ORDER BY
  FIELD(search_filter.job, 0, 4, 5, 1, 2, 6, 7, 3, 8, 9) ASC;
```

Result (as the table is empty):

```
| job | count_races |
+-----+-------------+
| 0   | 0           |
| 4   | 0           |
| 5   | 0           |
| 1   | 0           |
| 2   | 0           |
| 6   | 0           |
| 7   | 0           |
| 3   | 0           |
| 8   | 0           |
| 9   | 0           |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/PPgc3sXUvXuQbXB4NiPSU/3)

The more optimized version without co-related subquery is.

```
SELECT 
    search_filter.job
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN player.job IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS count_races
FROM (
  SELECT 
   0 AS job
  UNION
  SELECT
    4 AS job
  UNION
  SELECT
    5 AS job  
  UNION
  SELECT
    1 AS job
  UNION
  SELECT
    2 AS job   
  UNION
  SELECT
    6 AS job   
  UNION
  SELECT
    7 AS job  
  UNION
  SELECT
    3 AS job   
  UNION
  SELECT
    8 AS job  
  UNION
  SELECT
    9 AS job    
  # [...]
) AS search_filter
LEFT JOIN
 player
ON
 search_filter.job = player.job
GROUP BY 
 search_filter.job
ORDER BY
  FIELD(search_filter.job, 0, 4, 5, 1, 2, 6, 7, 3, 8, 9) ASC
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/PPgc3sXUvXuQbXB4NiPSU/4)

Comment: Thank you! You solved my problem, never had to build a query like this.